# Console.Writeline does not print the desired results

Tags: c#

what's wrong , console.writeline take a string argument followed by objects -up to 18 i think- !

```
Console.WriteLine( "Grade Report : \n",
"{0} grades was entered, total grade is : {1}\n",
"Class average : {2:F}\n",
"\nA : {3}, \nB : {4}, \nC : {5}, \nD : {6}",
gradeCounter, gradeTotal, ( double ) gradeTotal / gradeCounter,
aCount, bCount, cCount, dCount );
```

the output i get instead is :

```
Grade Report :
```

Thanks !

Comment: What output are you expecting? What output are you getting instead?

Comment: It looks like first three commas (,) should be plus (+)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper look the at the problem now, thanks

Comment: @Mehmet Ataş i use place holders {}, so no need for '+'.

Comment: Now, you have indicated the *actual* output, which is fine. However, you still have not indicated the *expected* output.

Answer (score 1):

In order to format the string with the provided variables, you need to remove the commas:

```
Console.WriteLine("Grade Report : \n" +
    "{0} grades was entered, total grade is : {1}\n" +
    "Class average : {2:F}\n" +
    "\nA : {3}, \nB : {4}, \nC : {5}, \nD : {6}",
    gradeCounter, gradeTotal, ( double ) gradeTotal / gradeCounter, aCount, bCount, cCount, dCount);
```

That's the method definition:

```
public static void WriteLine(string format, params Object[] arg)
```

So the first string is your template-string. Every argument separated by a comma is treated as an argument to replace a placeholder within that string.

Comment: Thank you, that's weird, i was thinking no need for + because of the use  of place holders .

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Console.WriteLine( 
    String.Format("Grade Report : \n {0} grades was entered, total grade is :{1}\n Class average : {2:F}\n\n A : {3}, \nB : {4}, \nC : {5}, \nD : {6}",
        gradeCounter, gradeTotal, 
        ( double ) gradeTotal / gradeCounter, aCount, bCount, cCount, dCount 
    )
);
```

[String.Format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format) method is used for placeholder/value replacement like `Console.WriteLine` also does. It's use is redundant here, so you can unwrap this function. But doesn't affect the output.

Comment: The explicit call to `String.Format` is redundant as there is a `WriteLine`-overload for that.

Comment: I wasn't sure if `console.writeline` accepted both format & args, so I gave an complete answer. Why the downvote? Won't that answer work as expected?

Comment: Well it will, but it adds complexity that's simply not neccessary.

Comment: If this is complex and hard to understand, everyone should stop coding.

Comment: Nonsense to downvote. The answer works, but it is not the best way to do it. Explain how `String.Format` works and the answer is good to go.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.WriteLine` expects parameterized string as first parameter and after comma it expects parameters. Also you can use `@` to format string with new lines. So you end up with the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(@"Grade Report : 
{0} grades was entered, total grade is : {1}
Class average : {2:F}
A : {3}, 
B : {4}, 
C : {5}, 
D : {6}",
1, 2, (double)3 / 4,
5, 6, 7, 8);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i like this solution i'll use it in the future, for know i solved the problem by replacing ',' with '+', the last string argument was followed by comma to inform the compiler that the next argument w'll be an object -variable-
Thank you !